# Connecting data source to CRM in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, odbc, oledb, crm

Intern at a company.  Learning SSIS.  When I am connecting a data source to CRM 4.0.  Am I to create connections for both OLE DB and ODBC or just ODBC?

Comment: To clarify: you're looking to use CRM as a source *only* or source and destination?

Comment: Im using CRM as destination and source.  I successfully created an ODBC connection already

Comment: I have an original data source x...am transferring data from x to crm and them from crm to database and from database to a tool Im building.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/05/07/integrating-crm-using-sql-integration-services-ssis.aspx

To be able to make updates and create records you really need to use a web service as described in the blog above.

OLE DB Drivers would help you connect to the SQL Database that CRM 4.0 is using, but that would be no different than just connecting to a MS SQL Database. If you want to transfer data, manipulating the database directly is unsupported (and a bad idea).